# "Unable to find assembly" exceptions with EntityFramework 6. What's going on?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

So we have a couple of students interning in the office and they're hitting our development DB pretty hard with some way to broad queries that pegs our servers CPU and memory.

Generally when they doing this work i begin to get weird EF6 errors at run-time:

> Unable to find assembly 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-MyProjectName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

And of course when they stop their queries executing then these error disappear.

---

**UPDATE:**
I have disabled Proxy creation for all my contexts by overriding the OnContextCreated method:

```
namespace Projectname.Entities.MyEntityDB
{
    public partial class MyEntityConn
    {
        public void OnContextCreated()
        {
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This has not changed the fact that i receive this error.

Also, i have verified that i am NOT putting any of these entities into Session...

---

I have a few questions around this:

1) Has anyone experienced this before and what is going on? Is it related to the DB not being accessible?
2) Is there any way to catch this type of error?
3) Is there any setting or configuration that i might be missing that would lesson this error?

Any help understand this better would be great. I'm hoping this is a scenario that won't follow the app into production.

TIA

Comment: I have faced a similar issue before and the only way to fix it is to turn off the proxy creation settings for EntityFramework.

Comment: Are you using Azure?

Comment: Might [this](http://www.adamtuliper.com/2010/09/aspnetmvcentity-framework-error-unable.html) help?

Comment: @Amy Yes we are. And it is scattered throughout the stack trace too...

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/issues/42) might help

Comment: Turning off proxies is a solution, in the same sense that your car has a flat fire and you stop driving your car.  You might not be driving on a flat now, but you still have a flat tire.

Comment: Updates made. Disabling ProxyCreation does not seem to resolve the error nor am i storing any entities in Session.